# Type field of Property not filled in for UML PrimitiveType in Xpand

Tags: uml, code-generation, xtend, acceleo, xpand

I have an XPT template that generates text from a UML model. This is the excerpt I use on the attributes of a class

```
«FOREACH attribute AS a»
    Id: «a.name»
    Type: «a.type.name»
«ENDFOREACH»
```

All works well as long as the `type` is a class from the model itself. But if it is a primitive type, then all of the fields, including the `name`, is set to `null`. If I change `«a.type.name»` to `«a.type»`, then the response is something like this:

```
org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.PrimitiveTypeImpl@6e315086 (eProxyURI:
     pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml#String)
```

The debugger shows that only the `eStorage` private field is set on the object that is why the `toString()` produces the output above.

Interestingly the same expression in Acceleo is evaluated correctly:

```
[query public getType(t : Type) : String = t.name /]
```

Question: how can I get the `type` field of attributes be filled in for primitive uml types in Xtend?

EDIT: Issue narrowed down to this question: [EProxy URI does not resolve in ecore model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213348/eproxy-uri-does-not-resolve-in-ecore-model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code generated by Acceleo can resolve the unusual `pathmap://` eProxyURIs. By default, a simple Xpand template or Xtend code can't resolve them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213348/eproxy-uri-does-not-resolve-in-ecore-model) for more details and the solution.

Comment: I got exactly the same problem today with Acceleo. But this solution didn't worked for me. In my model.uml file I tried to replace using a text editor all the occurrences of `pathmap://UML_LIBRARIES/UMLPrimitiveTypes.library.uml` with `http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/Types`. I also tried to replace with `http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/Types` and `http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20161101/PrimitiveTypes.xmi` without success. Any idea of what's going wrong? @thSoft

Answer (score 1):

My original solution is [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1094565&goto=1859906&#msg_1859906).

After two days of searching, I found the solution.

The solution is write here: http://kompilatory.iiar.pwr.edu.pl/wiki/index.php/Acceleo/Getting_Started_33#Generating_java_beans

I had to modify the MANIFEST.MF and the Generate.java file in the following way.

1. I had to add the org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources as a new dependency.
2. Moreover, I had to modify the Generate.java file in the following way.

2.1. The registerResourceFactories(ResourceSet resourceSet) method had to be set to "@generated NOT"

2.2. and the last line of the method had to be uncommented and added a semicolon ";" to the end of the line.
UMLResourcesUtil.init(resourceSet);

2.3. And finally, had to be added a new import line.
"import org.eclipse.uml2.uml.resources.util.UMLResourcesUtil;"