# EProxy URI does not resolve in ecore model

Tags: eclipse-emf, ecore

In my Ecore model all types that come from outside the current model are not resolved by their proxies. **All fields of the object returned by `getType()` are `null`** and only the storage type URI is filled in at runtime.

Here is an extract of my model:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ecore:EPackage xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" name="model" nsURI="http:///model.ecore" nsPrefix="model">
  <eSubpackages name="general" nsURI="http:///model/general.ecore" nsPrefix="model.general">
    <eClassifiers xsi:type="ecore:EClass" name="Address">
      <eStructuralFeatures xsi:type="ecore:EAttribute" name="street" ordered="false" lowerBound="1"
      eType="ecore:EDataType platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.uml2.types/model/Types.ecore#//String"/>
    </eClassifiers>
  </eSubpackages>
</ecore:EPackage>
```

Currently if I make an

```java
Address a = <address item from model>
Type t = a.getType();
```

all fields of `t` will be `null` and the `toString()` returns something like:

```
org.eclipse.uml2.uml.internal.impl.PrimitiveTypeImpl@6e315086 (eProxyURI:
 platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.uml2.types/model/Types.ecore#//String)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the proxy URIs from `platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.uml2.types/model/Types.ecore#//String` to contain the NS URI of the package that contains the data type: `http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/4.0.0/Types#//String`.

Note that *this change can only be done in a textual editor*.